# SQLAlchemy Rollback in MSSQL on Inserts

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to do multiple inserts to a MSSQL database by directly using the SqlAlchemy engine.

```
table = metadata.tables['TestTable']
ins = table.insert()
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.execute(ins, data)
```

The first insert will work not problem. The second insert will attempt to run then execute a rollback, which will then fail with the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('25000', '[25000' [FreeTDS][SQL Server]The ROLLBACK TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. (3903)(SQLEndTran)')
```

I have already altered the behavior of the queue pool to use reset_on_return="commit" so I am at a loss for why this is happening. Any ideas on how to allow multiple inserts?

Comment: Your example only does one insert. Are you saying running this code multiple times doesn't work?

Comment: Correct. Now the data variable is a list the contains many records, but the next time I try to run this it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that when there is an error in the transaction SQLAlchemy will still rollback, whether you set reset_on_return to "commit" or not. I was attempting to insert np.nan values from a pandas dataframe, causing the error.